# can i pass the variable arguments in SQL SERVER function or Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a situation where i have to retrieve the record set for different scenarios from same query. i mean, have to create a function or stored procedure can run for number of parameters if i pass 2 parameter then it can be able to work if i pass 3 parameter then also able to work and so on so. can we create a Sp or function where we can pass variable arguments in sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a stored procedure with optional (default) parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure
(
   @Param1 int = null,
   @Param2 int = null,
   ...
   @ParamN int = null)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

You could then call this as

```
EXEC TestProcedure 1
EXEC TestProcedure 1, 2
```

etc etc, up to

```
EXEC TestProcedure 1, 2 ... N
```

this would obviously imply an upper limit on the number of parameters, but if that's acceptable to you, it would achieve what you describe